# Hipchat Message with Groovy - Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation

Tags: json, groovy, unirest, hipchat

I'm having trouble with a Groovy script, attempting to post a message in Hipchat with Unirest.

```
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization Impossible. Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization Impossible. Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation.
at com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody.body(HttpRequestWithBody.java:155)
at com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody$body.call(Unknown Source)
at 011.run(011.groovy:15)
```

Thats the Script:

```
@Grab(group='com.mashape.unirest', module='unirest-java', version='1.4.9')
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest

def apiToken = " [Token] "

Unirest.clearDefaultHeaders()

Unirest.post("https://api.hipchat.com/v2/room/ [Number] /message" )
.header("Content-Type", "application/json" )
.queryString('auth_token', apiToken)
.body(["message": "Test", "notify": True])
.asString()
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `Map` to `.body(...)`, but the doc says it expects either a `String`, or a `JsonNode`, or an `Object`, and for `Object`s you will need more configuration to specify how they are serialized (and a `Map` falls in that category).

Maybe you can tell Groovy to generate a JSON String value for you, from your `Map` object:

```
.body(JsonOutput.toJson(["message": "Test", "notify": true]))
```

(`JsonOutput` is in package `groovy.json`)